# How to look up a word in macos dictionary with python subprocess

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

I am writing a script to open and search the macOS dictionary application

In terminal, I can do this

`open dict://cheeseburger`

and the app opens to the cheeseburger entry

Using python's subprocess module, I can do this:

`subprocess.Popen(["path_to_dictionary_app"])`

and the app opens

How do I include a search word in the subprocess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `Popen` is `subprocess.Popen(['command','arg1', 'arg2'])`.

In your case:

```py
search = 'cheeseburger'
args = ['open','dict://'+search]
subprocess.Popen(args)
```